# Python Terminal/Text UI (TUI) library

Tags: python, user-interface, console, console-application, tui

How can I make a console GUI (more appropriately called TUI) ?

It's important to note that I will be changing the text in some of the spots, and this is why I can't have it just print to the screen. It would be fine to use other modules, but I'd prefer not to have to. Here's an ASCII mockup of what it would look like:

```
           ********************************************
           *                                          *
           *                                          *         
           *                                          * 
           *      There are 8 seconds left.           *
           *                                          *         
           *                                          * 
           *                                          *
           *      The script has run 8 times          *         
           *                                          * 
           *                                          *
           *                                          *         
           *                                          * 
           ********************************************
```

I would need to be able to update the timer and the number of iterations dynamically.

I know how to write over the last printed line using the carriage return. But I can't use that on both lined.

Comment: take a look at [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#module-curses).

Comment: I'm on windows, so this doesn't work, but I might just install Cygwin

Comment: why don't you just create a real GUI instead of a console one

Comment: @JoranBeasley I'm making both...this is more of a personal exercise.

Comment: Your gonna spend far more time trying to develop a consol GUI for an operating system where no one uses a console.....

Comment: @JoranBeasley ik, like I said I have more of an interest in doing this for my own purpose than distributing it.

Comment: then your only chance is curses in Windows it's called  ncurses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [console application gui for python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664184/console-application-gui-for-python)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using the [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) module.

Here's [an introduction](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html).

Answer (score 24):

There is some libraries for that:

- [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/curses.html) which is python frontend to ncurses ([tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.10/howto/curses.html#curses-howto))
- [urwid](http://urwid.org/) ([tutorial](http://urwid.org/tutorial/index.html))
- [npyscreen](http://www.npcole.com/npyscreen/)
- [python-prompt-toolkit](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit)
- [curtsies](https://github.com/thomasballinger/curtsies)
- [asciimatics](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics)
- [picotui](https://github.com/pfalcon/picotui)

Comment: Another option would be PicoTUI (https://github.com/pfalcon/picotui)